# What is wrong with my code, meaning that no details entered still logs the user in?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, authentication

Ok, so to update. I have spoken to my professor who said that worrying about encrypted passwords/sql injection etc will wait until next term. For now, I should concentrate on the basics (no login granted if any (or both) fields are left empty, no user can login with their password but another users username etc.) I have now condensed my query into one, to check for username and password together, this prevents a login using a combination of one users password and anothers username or vice versa.

The code also won't log in if either one or both fields are left empty. My issue now is that my script alerts aren't popping up correctly. If both fields are left empty, it won't log in but it also won't have the script alert message pop-up. Same with a successful login, it will take you to the next page but won't popup with the welcome message. Can anyone tell me why? I have updated my code here to show how it looks now. Thanks!

```
protected void loginButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(userText.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(passText.Text)) return;
        {
            Response.Write("<script>alert('Details are incorrect, please try again');</script>");

            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["newregDBConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
            conn.Open();              
            var checkUser = "select count(*) from parent " +
                            "where parentID='" + userText.Text + "' " +
                            "and   password='" + passText.Text + "' ";
            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(checkUser, conn);
            int temp = Convert.ToInt32(com.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
            conn.Close();
            if (temp == 1)
            {
                conn.Open();
                string checkPassword = "select password from parent where password='" + passText.Text + "'";
                SqlCommand passCom = new SqlCommand(checkPassword, conn);
                var obj = passCom.ExecuteScalar();
                string password = obj?.ToString().Trim();
                if (password == passText.Text)
                {
                    Session["New"] = userText.Text;
                    Response.Write("<script>alert('Details are correct, welcome');</script>");
                    Response.Redirect("Payment.aspx");
                }
                else
                {
                    Response.Write("<script>alert('Details are incorrect, please try again');</script>");
                    userText.Text = "";
                    passText.Text = "";
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Response.Write("<script>alert('Details are incorrect, please try again');</script>");
                userText.Text = "";
                passText.Text = "";
            }
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: are you storing username in parentID column?

Comment: yes, username is the parentID (pk) in my db table.

Comment: I think [Little Bobby Tables' mom](https://xkcd.com/327/) might have a bit of fun here today.

Comment: You are vulnerable to SQL injection and you are storing passwords in the clear. Please consider using an "off-the-shelf" solution to authentication instead of rolling your own.

Comment: I understand it isn't secure and that there are multiple steps that I should take to secure it, but I am under the strain of a deadline and our professor has stated that next term we will move on to the security side of things, for now, we just need a functioning app to get an idea of things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the second query you only check passwords, not the username. So if there is *anybody* with an empty password, then *everybody* is let in with an empty password.

Doing two queries is not needed, it simply is better to do it all in one go:

```
var sql = "select count(*) from parent " +
          "where parentID='" + userText.Text + "' " +
          "and   password='" + passText.Text + "' ";
```

There are several other things to improve, e.g.:

- What if either text contains a single quote...
  *(answer: the query throws an error, or worse you get SQL injection problems)*
- What if hackers manage to copy your database...
  *(answer: then they know ALL passwords, because there is no hashing being done)*

But I guess that is for a later moment / different question.

Comment: Oh, man. I suggested the same and got minus. Although maybe I should to put better description in my answer. Nevermind, I'm voting for you.

Answer (score 1):

`string password = obj?.ToString().Trim();`

If `obj` is null, then the above expression will result in an empty string. Therefore when you:

`if (password == passText.Text)`

The above will succeed when `passText.Text` is also an empty string.

As an aside, you really should not be storing a plain text password either.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe just check at the beginning ? :

```
protected void loginButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if ( string.IsNullOrEmpty(userText.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(passText.Text)) return;
    // rest of the code ...

}
```

Aside from the above, you should make use of the `SqlCommand` object and use `SqlParameter` for safety.

instead of yours :

```
string checkUser = "select count(*) from parent where parentID='" + userText.Text + "'";
SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(checkUser, conn);
```

you can do :

```
string checkUser = "select count(*) from parent where parentId=@userName";
SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter("@userName", userText.Text);
SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(checkUser, conn);
com.Parameters.Add(param);
```

*Sidenote :*

To get rid of the problems [@Sefe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6859983/sefe) pointed out you can just check both ( password and username ) in one query :

```
string checkUser = "select [enter_some_column_name_here] from parent where parentId=@userName and password=@userPass";
SqlParameter paramUsername = new SqlParameter("@userName", userText.Text);
SqlParameter paramPassword = new SqlParameter("@userPass", passText.Text);
SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(checkUser, conn);
com.Parameters.Add(paramUsername);
com.Parameters.Add(paramPassword);
```

But that's still not enough. You're not encrypting user password in database and you're trying to compare raw user password. To fix this you should encrypt passwords before entering them into database and then compare encrypted versions of passwords :

```
byte[] buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetByes(passText.Text);
SqlParameter paramPassword = null;
using ( SHA512 sha= new SHA512Managed())
{
    byte[] hash = sha.ComputeHash(buffer);
    StringBuilder builder= new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < hash.Length; i++)
    {
        builder.Append(hash[i].ToString("x2"));
    }
    paramPassword  = new SqlParameter("@userPass", builder.ToString());
}
```

So being aware of encryption problem you should change this line :`SqlParameter paramPassword = new SqlParameter("@userPass", passText.Text);` into above piece of code.

Comment: This is a perfect fix for what I need right now, thank you!

Comment: @ACostea: You should really look into your code. It does not do what you want. You are having **huge** security issues, the biggest of which is that you are not checking username and password of the same user.

Comment: This fix will just fix the symptoms, it will not fix the underlying problem. "Anyone can log in with empty username and password." is not resolved by just not allowing empty input. The problem here is deeper and related to how the OP verifies his username/password.

Comment: Hmm, I see what you mean. I have just tested and using one users username with another users password still logs me in.. How do I make it so that it compares the details for one user?

Comment: @Sefe When i was learning php back in 2004 i had no idea about SQL Injection and I have done many unsecure login forms. And I learnt just because there was no people like you that will negate everything. We all know ( from your 20 comments in here ) that this is not safe and there's and SQLi problem but he will learn sooner or later when he'll have problem with that.

Comment: I don't negate everything. And my issue with this answer is not SQL injection or security. My problem is that it doesn't solve the problem, it just brushes over it.

Comment: I know, this question was started for one issue but as Sefe pointed out, the biggest one is that any username and password combination can be used to log in. Although my professor has stated security/sql injection/password encryption will be tackled next term, this issue will definitely lose me marks as it's basic login. I just don't know how to compare the details for one specific user

Comment: That is the solution to prevent empty strings being checked against data tables. But other problems, as I said he'll find later on as he did now. That's how you learn by fixing and finding problems one after another.

Answer (score 1):

I dont think you need two queries for this. You can do the same in just one:

**Disclaimer:** This code is unsafe and it just pretends to answer a specific question. Dont manage authentication like this.

```
"select count(*) from parent where parentID='" + userText.Text + "' and password='" + passText.Text + "'"
```

If this query returns 1 the user could be authenticated.

Annother tips you should consider to improve your code:

- SqlConnection implements IDisposable, wich means it can release for you unused resources when no longer needed by enclosing it in a using statement. This forces the connection to automatically close, even if an exception occurs. You can see examples here:
  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection(v=vs.110).aspx
- I don't know what are the security requirements for this application, but appart from the sql injection problem, it is not generally a good idea to store plain-text user passwords in a database. You should consider using an authentication framework to manage these problems for you, like ASP net Membership:
  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tw292whz.aspx

I hope this helps. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You are not checking for a specific username/password combination. You are checking first if a user with a username exists:

```
string checkUser = "select count(*) from parent where parentID='" + userText.Text + "'";
SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(checkUser, conn);
```

And then you are checking if *any* user with a specifc password exists:

```
string checkPassword = "select password from parent where password='" + passText.Text + "'";
SqlCommand passCom = new SqlCommand(checkPassword, conn);
```

So you just need *any* user without a username and *any* (other or the same) user without a password in the DB. Also, anyone can create a user account and use his password to log in as *any other* user.

You need to query for a combination of both, username **and** password.

There are two other dangerous issues in your code:

1. Never store passwords directly in your DB.
2. Never, ever, use the text of your text boxes directly in your SQL query.

This combination will make it ridiculously easy for even a newbie hacker to log in without requiring a password ([or do even worse with your DB](http://xkcd.com/327/)).

Comment: Sorry. You should really make more of it. It's a big problem.

Comment: @spender: It's a problem (yes, it's a big one), but off-topic to the question.

Comment: As a new user coming to the site, I wouldn't be concerned with reading the "whole question". I'd see several answers that seem to imply that it's quite alright to perpetuate insecure code.

Comment: @spender: I don't think "This combination will make it ridiculously easy for eaven a newbie hacker to log in without requiring a password." seems to imply that this is alright.

Comment: Like I stated above - I understand it isn't secure and that there are multiple steps that I should take to secure it, but I am under the strain of a deadline and our professor has stated that next term we will move on to the security side of things, for now, we just need a functioning app to get an idea of things. But thank you Sefe, your post put me on the right track, I was just writing my if statement wrong, but someone else gave me a correct one. Thanks!

Comment: @ACostea: "functioning" does not only mean that a user can log in. It also means that a user can not log in without the correct username and password. And your code doesn't secure that. If you don't fix it, this will have an effect on your grades.

Comment: I just commented on the other post above, I now see what you mean but I am unsure of how to test the username and password of a specific user rather than any username and any password!

Comment: @ACostea: The answer is in my post: "You need to query for a combination of both, username and password."

Comment: But, by combining both of the queries together, won't it be doing the same thing of checking for any username and then any password in the database table?

Comment: @ACostea: No it wouldn't. Two chained queries would be an `OR`. A combined query would be an `AND`. It is different to ask "do I find a user **or** a password that match?" than to ask "Do I find a user where both, username **and** password match."

Comment: Ok, I understand. So with a combined query, is a lot of my code under the button click event redundant? I'm trying to figure out where I would place the combined query. Do I not need the 'if(temp ==1)' statement now?

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you should check both, username and password at same query

```
select count(*) from parent where parentID='" + userText.Text + "' AND  password='" + passText.Text + "'"
```

Comment: @spender this is just sample to explain to OP what he probably missed. Its is not about SQL injections / code quality / storing non-encrypted passwords in database.

Comment: As a new user coming to the site, I wouldn't be concerned with reading the "whole question". I'd see several answers that seem to imply that it's quite alright to perpetuate insecure code.

Comment: Either way, changing my query to the one above gives me the same result, empty text boxes will still log the user in.

Comment: @spender partly agree. In my opinion, I wish to rewrite whole method. But this will not be as answer for OP question. Otherwise, if new user wont to read whole question, it is user's problem.

Comment: @ACostea if this ```select count(*) from parent where parentID='" + userText.Text + "' AND  password='" + passText.Text + "'"``` still returning ```1```, even if password is empty, you should check your data in DB and debug what exactly stored in your textboxes.